# Create new variable based on change in another variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Date': ["2011-10-19", 
              "2013-01-14", 
              "2014-05-27",
              "2014-06-23",
              "2014-08-12",
              "2014-09-22",
              "2014-09-22",
               "2014-09-22"
             ], 'Status': ["Pending", 
                           "Pending", 
                           "Complete", 
                           "Pending",
                          "Complete",
                           "Pending", 
                           "Pending", 
                           "Pending"],
             'Group': ["a",
                       "a",
                       "a",
                       "a", 
                       "b",
                       "b",
                       "b",
                       "b"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df
```

I would like to create another variable based on the change in Status over time for each group such that they are considered a "completer" the next row after they have Status = "Complete"

For example I would like to create the "completer" column in the df2 table:

```
df2 = {'Date': ["2011-10-19", 
              "2013-01-14", 
              "2014-05-27",
              "2014-06-23",
              "2014-08-12",
              "2014-09-22",
              "2014-09-22",
               "2014-09-22"
             ], 'Status': ["Pending", 
                           "Pending", 
                           "Complete", 
                           "Pending",
                          "Complete",
                           "Pending", 
                           "Pending", 
                           "Pending"],
             'Group': ["a",
                       "a",
                       "a",
                       "a", 
                       "b",
                       "b",
                       "b",
                       "b"],
             'Completer': ["Non-Completer",
                          "Non-Completer",
                          "Non-Completer",
                          "Completer",
                          "Non-Completer",
                          "Completer",
                          "Completer",
                          "Completer"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
df2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've sorted by Date so that the date each row is an increase in date from Oct 19 2011 to Sept 22 2014. I'd like to group by "Group" and create a completer variable that captures the change in Status such that any row within the group after Status = Complete the new column is Completer == "Completer". For example, in df2 row 4 the completer variable is now "completer" because the previous row (an earlier date) Status == Complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it in two steps.

Firstly I created a column which marks the first date that each group has "Completed", and added 1 to it so that we update values starting from the next row.

Secondly, since `True` / `False` translates to `1` / `0` respectively I used a `groupby` on Group and `cummax`, which would update all following rows per group to `True`.

Then lastly I just used `replace` and dropped the helping column.

```
df['first_date_per_group'] = df.index.isin(df.loc[df['Status'].eq('Complete')]['Group'].index + 1)

df = df.assign(Completer=df.groupby('Group')['first_date_per_group'].cummax()).replace(
    {True:'Completer',False:'Non-Completer'}).drop('first_date_per_group',axis=1)
```

prints:

```
         Date    Status Group      Completer
0  2011-10-19   Pending     a  Non-Completer
1  2013-01-14   Pending     a  Non-Completer
2  2014-05-27  Complete     a  Non-Completer
3  2014-06-23   Pending     a      Completer
4  2014-08-12  Complete     b  Non-Completer
5  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
6  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
7  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
```

Comment: It doesn't look like its picking up on the Status change. I had one group where all of the status was Pending and the first row of that group was Non-completer then all the other rows were Completer.

Comment: I'll double check my translation of the code is correct.

Comment: Oh maybe the issue is for groups where all of the rows are pending... I'll try to recreate

Answer (score 1):

use transform on the grouped data and assign 1 or nan, then ffill based on the group. this leaves the values from the past as null. Use that to fill the column as completer or non-completer

```
df['completer']=df.groupby('Group')['Status'].transform(
    lambda row: np.where(row.shift(1).eq('Complete'), 1, np.nan ) )
df['completer']=df.groupby('Group')['completer'].ffill()
df['completer'] = np.where(df['completer'].isna(), 'non-completer', 'completer')
df
```

```
Date    Status  Group   completer
0   2011-10-19  Pending     a   non-completer
1   2013-01-14  Pending     a   non-completer
2   2014-05-27  Complete    a   non-completer
3   2014-06-23  Pending     a   completer
4   2014-08-12  Complete    b   non-completer
5   2014-09-22  Pending     b   completer
6   2014-09-22  Pending     b   completer
7   2014-09-22  Pending     b   completer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method to `ffill` the 'completer' and then change the value to 'non-completer' and then do `bfill`

```
def fill_completer(g):
    g.loc[g['Status']=='Complete', 'Completer'] = 'Completer'
    g['Completer'] = g['Completer'].ffill()
    g.loc[g['Status']=='Complete', 'Completer'] = 'Non-Completer'
    g['Completer'] = g['Completer'].bfill()
    
    return g
```

Then apply it to each group as :

```
df['Completer'] = np.nan
df = df.groupby('Group').apply(fill_completer)
```

print(df):

```
         Date    Status Group      Completer
0  2011-10-19   Pending     a  Non-Completer
1  2013-01-14   Pending     a  Non-Completer
2  2014-05-27  Complete     a  Non-Completer
3  2014-06-23   Pending     a      Completer
4  2014-08-12  Complete     b  Non-Completer
5  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
6  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
7  2014-09-22   Pending     b      Completer
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I'd still like to add another, quite readable approach I came up with:

```py
df['Completer'] = (df.Status.shift()  # shift Status down by one row
                     .eq("Complete")  # mark "Complete" rows
                     .groupby(df.Group).cumsum()  # cumulative sum per group
                     .map({0: "Non-Completer", 1: "Completer"})  # replace 0s and 1s
                  )
```